# How to make a jQuery click event persist even after page post back

Tags: jquery, postback

I have a click handler which expandes and collapses the tree view, I want some mechanism where in, after post back the same node which were expanded/collapsed should remain as it is.
HTML:

```
 <ul>
        <li>Africa
            <ul>
                <li>Egypt</li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li>SA</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Asia
            <ul>
                <li>India</li>
                <li>China</li>
                <li>Japan</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Europe
            <ul>
                <li>UK</li>
                <li>France</li>
                <li>Germany</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>America
            <ul>
                <li>US</li>
                <li>Mexico</li>
                <li>Argentina</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('li:has(ul)')
    .click(function () {

            var that = this;
            $('li:has(ul)').children().filter(':visible').parent().each(function (x) {
                if (this != that)
                    toggle(this);
            });
            toggle(this);

    })
    .children().hide();

    $('li:not(:has(ul))').css({ cursor: 'default', 'list-style-image': 'none' });
});
```

Any help appreciated!!

Comment: mean?? even if the form is refreshed?? you want the view to retain it's position?

Comment: i think u should use the server side variable for that purpose , write a conditional loop and set some flag

Comment: Yes, I want the view to retain its position..

Answer (score 1):

You might try to encode url after your url just add  `#` and the fields which should be displayed 
like

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727626#field1;field
```

or

```
  http://example.com/your_action#field1;field
```

after that parse url

```
var fields = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('#') + 1).split(';');
```

and you will have fields to be displayed

expanding and collapsing will need to open url with # at the end;

**EDIT**

here is how to do it : 
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/firegnom/eRPM5/)

```
<ul>
    <li id='1'>Africa
        <ul>
            <li>Egypt</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>SA</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id='2'>Asia
        <ul>
            <li>India</li>
            <li>China</li>
            <li>Japan</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id='3'>Europe
        <ul>
            <li>UK</li>
            <li>France</li>
            <li>Germany</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id='4'>America
        <ul>
            <li>US</li>
            <li>Mexico</li>
            <li>Argentina</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$(function () {

    $('li:has(ul)')
    .click(function () {

           var that = this;

        $('li:has(ul)').children().filter(':visible').parent().each(function (x) {
                if (this != that)
                    toggle(this);
            });
            $(this).children().toggle();
        if (window.location.href.indexOf('#')>0){
          var href = window.location.href.slice(0,window.location.href.indexOf('#'));
        }else{
            var href = window.location.href
        }

       var ids ='' 

        $('li:has(ul:visible)').each(
            function(){
              ids=ids+$(this).attr('id')+';'
            }
        );     

          window.location =  href +'#'+ids;
    })
    .children().hide();

    $('li:not(:has(ul))').css({ cursor: 'default', 'list-style-image': 'none' });
    var fields = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('#') + 1).split(';');

        for (var i in fields){
        $('li#'+i).children().toggle();
        }
});
```